# Do containers use same kernel?

Tags: kernel, container

I wanted to know if all containers running on a particular Linux machine use same underlying host kernel. I read yes, they do use same underlying host's kernel and hence are light-weight and very fast.

I am not sure if different Linux flavors have same kernel at their heart.

If all of them have same kernel at the heart, then most probably my first assumption is right.

But, if all Linux flavors don't have same kernel... then my first assumption (that containers use host's kernel) must be wrong. Further, it must indicate that the image -using which containers are built- contain the whole OS including kernel.

Comment: "different Linux flavors have same kernel at their heart" what does that mean?

Comment: There's aren't Hosts Kernel for the same system

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a bit confused.  There is no single one thing that is known as "linux".  There are many linux versions, as blessed by Linus Torvalds, and then there are many slightly different versions of that, employed by different vendors.  Whichever kernel a given host machine is running is the one kernel on that particular system, and is shared by all containers running on that machine, but that is not to say that is the exact same kernel running on another machine.